# How to show 'Hello' once a second instead of showing five 'Hello' altogether in this program?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
#coding=utf-8
'''Tkinter module'''

from Tkinter import *
import time
root=Tk()
t=Text(root,fg='red')

t.pack()
def insert_hello_into_text_area():
    t.insert(1.0,'Hello')

Button(root,text='hello',command=insert_hello_into_text_area).pack()

def start():
    i=0
    while i<5:
        t.insert(1.0,'Hello\n')
        time.sleep(1)
        i+=1

Button(root,text='start',command=start).pack()


root.mainloop()
```

This is a python program using Tkinter module. When I click 'start' button, I could not get one 'hello' each second. Instead, all 'Hello' will appear five seconds later. So how to show 'Hello' once a second instead of showing five 'Hello' altogether in this program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `while` loop with `time.sleep`, use [`after`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method).

`after` call the callback after `n` (1000 in following code) milliseconds.

```
def start(times=5):
    t.insert(END, 'Hello\n')
    if times > 1:
        root.after(1000, lambda: start(times-1))
```

Comment: @fisiksnju, Without lambda `start(..)` is called, not after 1000 ms, but immediately, and the return value of the `start` function is used as callback, but it is not a function, but `None`.

Comment: @fisiksnju, The second argument to `after` should be a callable object. (function, method, ....)